# What does casting do?

Tags: c++

Should be 7 in ASCII the output?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 
int main() {
    char a = '7'; 
    int b = 7;
    cout << (char)b;
}
```

Comment: No, numbers aren't casted to ASCII, and ASCII chars aren't casted from digits to the corresponding integer values.

Comment: You program should 'ring the bell' (or make some other alert sound). The ASCII character with a value of 7 is `bel`.

Comment: There is no known encoding where `'7' == 7`. It's definitely not the case with ASCII where `'7'` is `55`.

Comment: And please don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`, it's [a really bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). As is [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: why is it a bad habit :"using namespace std"?

Comment: Please follow the links and read.

Comment: @Fabbiucciello because the namespace is there for a reason.  Moving the entire namespace to the global namespace removes the protection.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly not, because the ASCII code for '7' is 0x37 (55).  ASCII 7 is the BEL control character.  If supported by the particular environment you run it on, it will issue some alert sound or beep.

In this case the cast causes `std::ostream::operator<<(char)` rather then `std::ostream::operator<<(int)` to be called, emitting the character BEL (`'\a'` or 7) to be emitted rather then presenting a decimal string representing the integer value 7.

Comment: std::ostream::operator<<(int) what does it mean ?

Comment: @Fabbiucciello This is the overloaded stream operator for formatted output of `int`: [std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(int)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt). It makes that `std::cout << 123;` does what it does.

Comment: @Fabbiucciello  Maybe you should post that as a separate questuion. `<<` is an overloaded operator of the `ostream` class; it is not _built-in_ to the language.  When you use `<<` and the left-hand operand is an `std::ostream` object (as `cout` is), then an `ostream` member function called `operator<<` is called of which there are several versions, and the one called depends on the _type_ of the right-hand operand.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/